# How do I handle auto-generated IDs in a RESTful API?

Tags: api, rest

When designing a RESTful API that uses a datastore that makes use of auto-generated IDs (and there aren't any reliable unique values otherwise), how do I specify an add (PUT) operation?

For example:

```
GET /widgets/
```

Would return a list of all widgets.

```
GET /widgets/123
```

Would return information for a specific widget.

```
POST /widgets/123
```

Would update a widget.

But what's the URL for adding a widget?

```
PUT /widgets/???
```

i.e., I (as the client) don't know the ID until I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST conventions typically specify a POST for creation and a PUT for updating. This is because PUT along with GET and DELETE are idempotent methods. Meaning that they can be run any number of times and the state of the server should be the same. POST is a non-idempotent action though, which means that the server state is not guaranteed to be the same after running the action each time.

Typically you would POST to the `/widgets` url to add an item.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_Web_services) for more detail.

Comment: Ah okey dokey I've got those the wrong way around. I'm sure the article I was reading said they were the other way around, but there's plenty of mis-information out there.

Comment: @stusmith: There's huge amounts of mis-information, but POST to the parent is right (ID allocation is not idempotent) and it should return a link/redirect to the resource just created.

Comment: @stusmith  You can create resources with either PUT or POST, the limitation with PUT is you need to know where to PUT it, therefore in your case you would need to know the ID in advance.  You can also update resources with PUT, POST or PATCH depending on what makes the most sense, which is why people get so confused trying to map HTTP methods to CRUD.

Comment: A particular POST operation may or may not be idempotent.  The point is, intermediaries don't know.  The only reason I point this out is because I've seen people make comments about not being able to use POST because there server is not being updated, which is obviously incorrect.